# How to lazy load with specific number of items in scrollview in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to develop an app where a screen contains news feed loading data from a certain api which loads around 100 of the data. I would like to paginate it like first load 10 data then scroll more to get more data and so on.Which is also referenced as infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You should use below example for pagination in scrollview or flatlist. Paste your url(API) here and run.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Platform,
    ActivityIndicator
} from "react-native"

class FlatlistPagination extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            //Loading state used while loading the data for the first time
            serverData: [],
            //Data Source for the FlatList
            fetching_from_server: false
            //Loading state used while loading more data
        }
        this.offset = 1
        //Index of the offset to load from web API
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://aboutreact.com/demo/getpost.php?offset=" + this.offset)
            //Sending the currect offset with get request
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => {
                //Successful response from the API Call
                this.offset = this.offset + 1
                //After the response increasing the offset for the next API call.
                this.setState({
                    serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.results],
                    //adding the new data with old one available in Data Source of the List
                    loading: false
                    //updating the loading state to false
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    }
    loadMoreData = () => {
        //On click of Load More button We will call the web API again
        this.setState({ fetching_from_server: true }, () => {
            fetch("http://aboutreact.com/demo/getpost.php?offset=" + this.offset)
                //Sending the currect offset with get request
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseJson => {
                    //Successful response from the API Call
                    this.offset = this.offset + 1
                    //After the response increasing the offset for the next API call.
                    this.setState({
                        serverData: [...this.state.serverData, ...responseJson.results],
                        //adding the new data with old one available in Data Source of the List
                        fetching_from_server: false
                        //updating the loading state to false
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error)
                })
        })
    };

    renderFooter() {
        return (
            //Footer View with Load More button
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.9}
                    onPress={this.loadMoreData}
                    //On Click of button calling loadMoreData function to load more data
                    style={styles.loadMoreBtn}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Load More</Text>
                    {this.state.fetching_from_server ? (
                        <ActivityIndicator color="white" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} />
                    ) : null}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.loading ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                ) : (
                        <FlatList
                            style={{ width: "100%" }}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                            data={this.state.serverData}
                            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                                <View style={styles.item}>
                                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                                        {item.id}
                                        {"."}
                                        {item.title.toUpperCase()}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            )}
                            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
                            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
                        //Adding Load More button as footer component
                        />
                    )}
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingTop: 30
    },
    item: {
        padding: 10
    },
    separator: {
        height: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: "black"
    },
    footer: {
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "row"
    },
    loadMoreBtn: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#800000",
        borderRadius: 4,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    btnText: {
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: "center"
    }
})

export default FlatlistPagination
```

Comment: Hello, You did here with pagination that is with offset, but is there anyway without offset. I mean getting the whole array of data and rendering in bunch of 10 ?